# how do i get a font from a website?

Tags: fonts

I am seeing the font web `Means` font from https://ux.mailchimp.com/patterns/typography
Is there a way to grab this font in any way?

```
font-family: "Means Web",Georgia,Times,"Times New Roman",serif;
```

[image]

Comment: It is possibly their own created font. So not for sale.

Comment: yeah am aware, so no way to download the font? how is the browser rendering the font?

Comment: why are you worried about legal right to use? i could be using it locally on my laptop for what its wort...no need to always go bunkers on simple questions...question is how to download...why worry if i commit murder with it?

Comment: @uberrebu you can easily google how to find custom fonts being used on websites. Usually you can find them using Network tab.  But this one is their brand font and not for sale. You're not advised to do it. It would be illegal to do so.

Comment: You can find similar fonts online, even free.

Comment: nopes..wont be illegal to do so..it is public...it will be illegal if i use it on a website for example or anything beyond private/non-public use without permission from them...stop spreading fear

Comment: You realize this site is populated by users that make a living from their intellectual property... and you are asking how to take, without permission, the intellectual property of another. If the owner wanted the font for everyone to use, they'd make it available to everyone. Just like taking and using copyrighted images from Google Image Search is less than ethical, so is taking fonts by scouring markup for them.

Comment: @uberrebu If the font does not allow usage, it is illegal. It doesn’t matter whether you’re only using it on your own computer or elsewhere. If you do not have the right to obtain the font (which you do not with Means), it is illegal to even download it. Stop spreading misinformation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it borderlines illegal activity. Relevant [meta discussion here](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1187/how-should-we-deal-with-questions-that-border-on-illegal-activity-id-fraud)

Answer (score 3):

Means is a [custom font designed by Commercial Type for Mailchimp](https://commercialtype.com/news/means_for_mailchimp). It belongs to Mailchimp and you can't buy the right to use it at any price.

[image]

Fortunately, it's based on Cooper by Oz Cooper (sometimes Cooper Old Style) which is now in the public domain, and other designs have been published inspired by this design. Check out [Newlyn's New Kansas](https://newlyn.com/fonts/new-kansas/) or Cooper BT.

[image]

Answer (score -5):

Fonts can be grabbed by inspecting the network tab and isloating elements to only `font` for easy find

[image]

from that it leads you to the css file for the font `typefaces.css`

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Means Web";
  src: url(/release/1.1.15f007016564549c82ed7fac0b9d6940a3cc2cb77/css/fonts/means/Means-Light-Web.woff2)
      format("woff2"),
    url(/release/1.1.15f007016564549c82ed7fac0b9d6940a3cc2cb77/css/fonts/means/Means-Light-Web.woff)
      format("woff");
  font-weight: 300;
  font-display: fallback;
}
```